# Dynamically Add a overlay view on top of a fragment android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have this requirement where I have a fragment Instance and I want to dynamically add a view on the top of the fragment irrespective of the root viewGroup of the Fragment.

Something like this

[image]:

- So is it possible to get the root view of the fragment from its instance? I know for activity I can do this: `activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content);`
- Also since a fragment can have any type of view group as its rootview like LinearLayout, RecyclerView, RelativeLayout, FrameLayout, Is there a generic way to add an overlay view on the top of the fragment?

If it is not possible then should I just add a dummy view on top of the fragment in xml layout and then use that view to add the overlay?

Comment: You should be able to do activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content); from inside a fragment, it's against the idea of fragment managing it's own layout only but it should work IMO. Or should the overlay be only for the Fragment and not the Activity?

Comment: I want fragment's rootView not the activity's.

Comment: ok, so just make the Fragment layout root element a FrameLayout and use it, won't this solve the issue?

Comment: I can not enforce FragmentLayout as fragment's root element as I am writing a library to be used by any application.

Comment: Bit unsure of what you're asking. Ordinarily of course the root view for the `Fragment` is whatever is inflated inside `onCreateView()`, and is accessible with `getView()` - but I'm guessing this isn't what you want?

Comment: @PPartisan the issue is the root view isn't a known layout so he can't add the overlay to it.

Comment: @PPartisan I just have the reference to the fragment. I am writing a library which any application with fragment can use and pass its reference and then the library should be able to add an overlay on the top of fragment. Whatever I am asking might not be possible and I might have to ask the application using the library to provide me a subview on the top of the fragment where I can add the overlay, but I was hoping if someone could tell me.

Comment: @pgiitu If you have a reference to the Fragment, am I right in saying you can then call `getView()` on it? That will return a `View` containing the fragment's root layout. You could then use an ugly if-else block with `instanceof` to determine its type, or use overloaded methods.

Comment: You could traverse up the layout Hierarchy til you find a Frame/Relative layout - it might give some weird results. :)

Comment: @PPartisan I think it would work. I missed the getView method. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @pgiitu NP. I'll type up an answer going into a bit more detail.

Comment: @PPartisan Sure. Thanks.

Comment: This will fail if parent view is a LinearLayout, or any other Layout that extends directly from ViewGroup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getView()` method returns a `View` that contains the Fragment's root layout. From there you could either cast it to `ViewGroup` and leave it at that to add a simple view, use an `if-else` block with `instanceof` to determine its type:

**First:**

```
ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) fragment.getView();
```

**Second:**

```
View view = fragment.getView();
if (view instanceof FrameLayout) {
    FrameLayout root = (FrameLayout) view;
} else if (view instanceof RelativeLayout) {

}

//etc...
```

**Third:**

**Edit:** Removed this option. It actually wont work.

Comment: This will fail if parent view is a LinearLayout, or any other Layout that extends directly from ViewGroup.

Comment: Just add another branch, `else if (view instanceof LinearLayout)` etc. Best option may be to cast `getView()` to `ViewGroup` thought and just work with that. That should provide enough functions to create a basic layout.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Child Fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager()) but if you are only interested in the Fragments root view, just retain the View you are returning in the fragments [onCreateView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle)) method

Comment: Can you elaborate how can I use childFragment ? Actually I am writing a library which should be able to add the overlay given the fragment instance. I don't want to force the application to pass in the rootView. Also since fragment can inflate any type of viewgroup is there a way to add the overlay on the top of fragment?